# How to add school email to mail client?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I'm having trouble connecting my school email to my Mail client (works fine for my personal), is this because of the university routing to their own system? It uses gmail but I have no idea how to figure out the IMAP settings to let me add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just selecting gmail as your provider should just work not problem.  See below for settings.

[image: Gmail Settings]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the account as "Other" not "Gmail". Then you'll have to enter all the relevant information using the image below as a template. Be sure to set the servers for gmail accordingly.

[image]